# Programmatically or declaratively demand client certificate for a single asp.net page in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

The title pretty much says it, I've rolled out an IIS 7 website with an SSL certificate and now willing to set "SSL Settings/Client certificates/Accept" for a single page but *programmatically or declaratively*. I've found a way of doing this using the IIS manager but due to some infrastructure limitations we need to be able to configure it without having access to IIS Manager.

Any pointers shall be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: A quick and dirty solution maybe just to check for HTTPS in your code-behind: `Request.IsSecureConnection`

Comment: And what happens next? i.e. in pseudocode I'd write if(Request.IsSecureConnection) { Request.RaiseClientCertificatePrompt(); }, and what I am looking for is "RaiseClientCertificatePrompt"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347649%28VS.90%29.aspx

It's the managed code sdk for IIS7. It can do most things to IIS, surely what you want is in there?