# IIS - SSL Settings with client certificate Accept

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis, client-certificates

I have configured IIS with SSL and also set the client certificate to "Accept" 
But, when I try to accept the web page, the browser does not prompt for client certificate.

With this code. `var cert = Request.ClientCertificate` 
But, I don't see any certificate in cert what so ever.

What's missing?

[image: IIS SSL Settings]

IIS 7.0 - Windows 2008 32 bit - ASP.NET 4.0

Comment: [This provides detail](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907274) on those options. Hth...

Comment: Yes. I have read that. According to that "If you choose to accept certificates, your server will prompt for a certificate but will not necessarily deny access if a certificate is not provided. " is not happening in our case. The browser does not prompt for certificate.

Comment: Do you need an authorization rule to deny anonymous & force the client to present a cert?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145348/programmatically-or-declaratively-demand-client-certificate-for-a-single-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Force the certificate prompt by using the `require` for a specific location [in web.config](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/access):

```xml
<location path="Home/CertPrompt">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

In order to do this, you have to modify your `applicationHost.config` like so (access from Deny -> Allow):

```xml
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`
```

Comment: The same setting prompts for client cert, if it is a windows 2008 R2. But does not prompt in windows 2008 32 bit. I'll try your solution on 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

URL has to be https which may be obvious to most. It's got me when testing locally on http. I just choose Accept and not require ssl, which is handled with redirects. Also encountered in chrome windows today if no client certificate is installed the prompt did not fire. I believe my android chrome app did prompt without certificates present. Mixed bag. Mac is a whole other experience.